# Why is gets throwing an error when arguments are passed to my ruby script?

Tags: ruby, gets

I'm using `gets` to pause my script's output until the user hits the enter key.  If I don't pass any arguments to my script then it works fine.  However, if I pass any arguments to my script then gets dies with the following error:

```
ruby main.rb -i
main.rb:74:in `gets': No such file or directory - -i (Errno::ENOENT)
    from main.rb:74:in `gets'
    ...
```

The error message is showing the argument I passed to the script.  Why would gets be looking at ARGV?

I'm using OptionParser to parse my command line arguments.  If I use `parse!` instead of `parse` (so it removes things it parses from the argument list) then the application works fine.

So it looks like gets is reading from ARGV for some reason.  Why?  Is this expected?  Is there a way to get it to not do that (doing `gets()` didn't help).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ruby will automatically treat unparsed arguments as filenames, then open and read the files making the input available to `ARGF` (`$<`).  By default, `gets` reads from ARGF.  To bypass that:

```
$stdin.gets
```

It has been suggested that you could use `STDIN` instead of `$stdin`, but it's usually [better to use `$stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279689/238886).

Additionally, after you capture the input you want from `ARGV`, you can use:

```
ARGV.clear
```

Then you'll be free to `gets` without it reading from files you may not have intended to read.

Answer (score 4):

The *whole point* of `Kernel#gets` is to treat the arguments passed to the program as filenames and read those files. The very first sentence in [the documentation](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/ruby-1.9/classes/Kernel.html#M002605) reads:

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*)

That's just how `gets` works. If you want to read from a *specific* `IO` object (say, `$stdin`), just call `gets` on that object.